# Javascript callback coding style in C?

Tags: javascript, c

Ok this question may be shocking for javascript haters and hard-core developers, forgive me!

I love the way I can write a callback function in javascript

```
var on = function(isTrue, doThis) {if (isTrue) doThis();}
```

Is there any possibility to replicate the same idea in C ? I know it's type dependent.
More and less this is my case:

I have multiple booleans and multiple filters so my use would be, instead of writing

```
if (thisIs == true) executeThisVoid(passingThisStruct)
```

I would love to write:

```
on(thisIs, function(struct){ do this and this})
```

or simply

```
on(thisIs, executeThisVoid);
```

Many thanks everybody.

Comment: Yes, but it requires accepting and passing pointers to functions. :(

Comment: Why is that bad? Could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: It's not *bad*. It's ugly and hard to read compared with Javascript.

Comment: coool no idea how to use them properly for this exact case though. :)

Comment: @Gaurav Meh. It's only hard to read if you're not comfortable with reasonable C usage. IMO callbacks are callbacks; and it's a pretty minor syntactical difference.

Comment: This is a new feature in C++11 called lambdas, unlikely to appear in C.  You might find [compound statements in GCC](http://walfield.org/blog/2010/08/25/lambdas-in-c.html) an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here goes. First define on:

```
void on(int thisIs, void (*executeThis)(void)) {
    if (thisIs)
        (*executeThis)();
}
```

Then, define someVoid:

```
void someVoid(void) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Then, within another function, call on:

```
on(1, someVoid);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, in C you can point to functions... so, If on is a method that get two function pointers, and thisIs is a function pointer, and executeThisVoid is alos one, you should not have any problems, just need to hold the struct in an outer scope, or create another struct that will represents a chain of method calling(to hold parameters and other stuff).